# Magit doesn't show diff highlighting until hunk is active

Tags: magit

I recently started encountering a new issue, and I'm not sure why. When opening a Magit status buffer, the diff highlighting doesn't appear until I select a hunk, in which case it appears for just that hunk. When I select another hunk, the highlighting remains.

How can I get the highlighting to always appear?

When first opening status buffer:
[image: When first opening status buffer]

After selecting a hunk:
[image: After selecting a hunk]

Comment: In my environment, it seems that it is working as you wish, highlighted immediately without any setting for the latest version magit (20230317.1751@melpa).

Comment: Can you check the value of `magit-diff-refine-hunk`? Try setting it to `all'.